why Xamarin App Hang on iOS 18 beta version if we use NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(this, false);
Hi team I am using flyoutpage in my,App facing hang issue in iOS 18 beta version when I using this "NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(this, false);"but when I remove this line from code a user see extra space from he status bar.
enter image description here
My Exception is is there any alternative way to remove the extra space from the top of the status bar in iOS

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

We had a similar problem with our Xamarin app. It happens only to the TabbedPage, and when this is set in xaml:
NavigationPage.HasNavigationBar="False"

Or, similarly, when this called in the constructor:
NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(this, false);

The solution for us is to only call the above in the OnAppearing override method.

This solution worked for me! Thanks

This solution works for me as well! Thank you!

This works for me also, thanks

OMG thank you!!! I didn't have idea this had something to do with the navigation bar!! This happens also with MasterDetailPage (I guess FlyoutPage too) and, quite weird, only if it's the first page to be shown.

Only setting:
NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(this, false)

in the OnAppearing() virtual method worked for me in terms of eliminating the freeze. However, this caused some additional problems with layouts as well as showing an animation when the navigation bar is removed.
Calling in OnSizeAllocated() like so does not freeze and does not have the knock-on effects of layout issues and distracting UI animations:
protected override void OnSizeAllocated(double width, double height)
{
    if(NavigationPage.GetHasNavigationBar(this))
        NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(this, false);

    base.OnSizeAllocated(width, height);
}


This solution makes sense, and indeed the animation is distracting. Unfortunatel,y in the case of TabbedPage, it did not work to solve the problem for me. It still hanged with a blank page.

What I had (only starting from iOS 18, beta ATM): blank page at first, less width, etc. issues. I googled and also found the issue is with NavigationPage, so the fix is pretty simple - just drop it from MainPage (my app is still using Xamarin.Forms 3.4):
instead of
MainPage = new NavigationPage(new RootPage());

I started using
MainPage = new RootPage();

BTW I have this legacy app, but I almost rebuild it with MAUI (haven't released it yet), so I'll recommend you to upgrade as well - as MAUI is much more mature (has also some bugs, but they at least might be fixed)

If we use that, fixs the problem, but it causes another issue when we try to PushAsync to some page. How did you do?
